# Deploying dockerized web app into a closed system

Tags: docker, deployment, production-environment, docker-image

We have to deploy a dockerized web app into a closed external system(our client's server).
(our image is made of gunicorn, nginx, django-python web app)

There are few options i have already considered:

- option-1) using docker registries: push image into registry, pull
  from client's system run docker-compose up with pulled image
- option-2) docker save/load .tar files: docker save image in local dev
  environment, move .tar file into the client's system and run docker load
  (.tar file) there.

Our current approach:

- we want to move source code inside a docker image(if possible).
- we can't make our private docker registry public --yet--(so option-1 is gone)
- client servers are only accessible from their internal local network(has no connection to any other external network)
- we dont want to copy all the files when we make an update(to our app), what we want to do is somehow detect diff or changes on docker image and copy/move/update only changed parts of app into client's server.(option-2 is gone too)

Is there any better way to deploy to client's server with the approach explained above?

PS: I'm currently checking "docker commit": what we could do is, docker load our base image into client's server, start container with that image and when we have an update we could just copy our changed files into that container's file system, then docker commit(in order to keep changed version of container). But the thing i don't like in that option is we would need to keep changes in our minds, then move our changed files(like updated .py or .html files) to client's server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can  ask you clients to configure VPN  on their intra network. So that you can push the changes to private docker registry which will be running on Client's intra network.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, but we don't want to create another dependency for a small web app on client's system/network  ᷅\_(ヅ)_/ ᷄

Comment: Given your requirements as stated, you can't use Docker, for exactly the reasons you identified.  (`docker load` only works on complete images so even if you went to great lengths to produce a layer that had a specific update, you'd still have to transfer and load the entire updated image.)  Please forget about `docker commit`: it doesn't help this problem and leads to "special" hand-built images, using it at all is almost never a best practice.

Comment: Ok Got it.  If possible to run small script on client machine then you  can use SSH tunneling  approach.  For that you can use ngrok https://ngrok.com/.     This will open the specific port in public (from the intranet).  You can open docker registry port to public and access it.    Once deployment done, you can kill the tunneling. But  once again, you need to configure docker registry on client machine.